# Can I change a workitem state based on updating a field?

Tags: tfs

I have a client that would like to configure TFS so that if a field is modified the User Story is sent back to "new".

I tried setting up a rule around System.State but the COPY rule is not allowed (gee I wonder why... no, no I totally get how bad a change there could be :-P)..

Comment: You can add a rule to the field that requires the State field to be New when changed, but as far as I know the user needs to make that change in the UI. It would have the same end-result.